# gitignore: !text.lib (exclude) vs *.lib (ignore)

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have question regarding ignore and exclude rules in .gitignore.

So I have a very large file tree where I want to ignore all lib files except a specific lib file which is a text file with a .lib extension:

What I have in my .gitignore file:

```
# exclude rule
!text.lib
# ignore rule
*.lib
```

However, I can not see all the text.lib files in my file tree when issuing a git status. The '!text.lib' is overrulled by *.lib'

How to make a rule that can solve this?

Thank you very much:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reinclude a pattern which was ignored before you have to specify it after the pattern which ignores it.

From the [gitignore documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again.

So your ignore file has to look like this:

```
*.lib
!text.lib
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the answer for this stackoverflow question. [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

You will just need to change expressions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that the files are spread all over a large file tree. So far, I have different versions of test.lib placed in over 50 different directories. So I would really prefer a generic rule, rather that having to specify a exclude rule for every directory containing a test.lib file. Am I missing something?